# Pre select primeng dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have a value and I need to put it in the dropdown at start:

```
state is an object {'code':...,'description'}

and listState in array of state 

 loadValue(stateSave: Object) {//state save is the object  just saved
   this.state={'code':stateSave['code'],'description':stateSave['description']   }
```

and in my html is:

```
    <p-dropdown [options]="listState" [(ngModel)]="state"  optionLabel="description"></p-dropdown>
```

My problem is that if I have an old value just saved and I want to show it but the dropdown doesn't work, because at start it doesn't show anything. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In init() method, write the below code,

```js
this.state={'code':stateSave['codice'],'description':stateSave['description']}
```

Comment: write the exact object you have to set by default.

Comment: sorry surendra, when I paste my code I wrong to publish now I have correct ( because I have just do what you suggest)